# External port checking services claim my port is closed even though I opened it

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I have a FRITZ!Box 7590 and I opened some ports for GTA online for two computers as [adviced by rockstar games](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/200525767/Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-PC-Connection-Troubleshooting).

[image]

But if I [check the port online](https://portchecker.de/), then it says it is closed.

[image]

I have GTA online running in the background with an open online session.

How can I even play the game online with these necessary ports closed?

Notes:

- ArcherC6 is an access point connected to the fritz.box, which I use as a repeater and switch.
  -- Both computers (BLUEBEAM--Gast and Black) are connected with it.
- I've also added a TCP port 7800 for testing. It says closed as well.

Comment: It shouldn’t be required to forward a port to participate in GTA online as clients are not hosts. Unless your problem is [NAT Type](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/206210548/How-to-Resolve-Errors-in-GTA-Online-about-Strict-NAT-Type). My first question would be are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: But GTA online is a peer-to-peer game, isn't it? So I could be the host sometimes. I never heard CGNAT.
https://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV_PC/comments/3889vn/comment/crt54bq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Try this tool, that really fires nmap which is a port scan utility https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/#:~:text=Nmap%20Online%20Port%20Scanner,perform%20an%20external%20port%20scan.

Answer (score 1):

It could that tool is blocked in the network of your ISP, or that your ISP blocks port checking. There are enterprise/telco carrier firewalls who can block that and most consumer grade ISPs have that in place as a security measure for their customers.

Answer (score 0):

In the very simplest terms, ports are not 'the same' both ways. Inbound & outbound are handled very differently, for security.

You should be able to see out, but you don't want other people being able to see in. Ports for a local service connecting outwards shouldn't need specifically opening, or any specific firewall rules, they should just open automatically for you as you launch the app & connect.

Comment: Ok, I tried to open the ports, because rockstar instructed me to open them.
https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/200525767/Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-PC-Connection-Troubleshooting

Comment: They don't need to be open both ways. The game itself will open outbound ports as necessary, on any regular domestic router. The inbound ports should stay closed [or even stealthed, so they don't appear in a portscan at all.] I can't read the German in your question, so idk what that's telling you.